# Windows Server Appfabric Caching Timeouts

Tags: caching, windows-server-2008-r2, appfabric

We have an application that uses Windows Server AppFabric Caching. The cache is on the local machine, local cache is not enabled. Here is the configuration in code, none in .config.

```
DataCacheFactoryConfiguration configuration= new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();
configuration.Servers= servers;
configuration.MaxConnectionsToServer= 100; // 100 is maximum
configuration.RequestTimeout= TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds( 1000);
```

Object expiration on PutAndUnLock is two minutes.

Here are some typical performance monitor values:

```
Total Data Size Bytes 700MB
Total GetAndLock Requests /sec Average 4
Total Eviction Runs: 0
Total Eviced Objects: 0
Total Object COunt: either 0 or 1.8447e+019 (suspicious, eh?) I think the active object count should be about 500.
```

This is running on a virtual machine, I don't think we are hardware constrained at all.

**The problem:** every few minutes, varies from 1 to 20, for a period of one second or so, all requests (Get, GetAndLock, Put, PutAndLock) timeout.

The only remedy I've seen online is to increase RequestTimeout. If we increase to 2 seconds the problem seems to happen somewhat less frequently, but still occurs. We can't increase the timeout more because we need the time to create the object from scratch after the cache times out.

Comment: how frequently are calls to Put/PutAndLock operations?

Comment: @AshokD, We were doing hundreds of Put/PutAndLock per minute. However, I've solved this problem by switching to <a href="http://memcached.org/" title="MemCache">MemCache</a>: no errors, less memory, faster.